# Iterate from a list to return data

Tags: python, json, list

I am having trouble over getting all the recorded data based on the parameter on list.

I have this list:

```
Par1 = ['Hospital 1', 'Hospital 2', 'Hospital 3', ....]
Par2 = ['BloodTypeO']
```

And below functions:

```
def convert_data_json(data, path)
    *(my function for writing json data dump)*

def data(par1, par2):
    data = *load from API*
    path = *my path*
    convert_data_json(data, path)

def all_parms(all_parms)
    Par1 = par1
    Par2 = par2
    for Par1 in all_parms:
         return data(Par1, Par2)
```

I am able to generate the json file with the naming format of `par1_par2.json` in my directory, but something is off in my def all_parms function, because I only able to generate 1 file from the first record in the `list => Hospital 1_BloodTypeO.json.`

Basically what I am trying to achieve is generate all this files: `Hospital 1_BloodTypeO.json, Hospital 2_BloodTypeO.json, Hospital 3_BloodTypeO.json`, etc

Would be very helpful if someone can help me on this.

Thank you

Comment: That's because you're using `return` inside the `for` loop, and it returns from the function in the first iteration. You should finish the loop and then return a list outside the loop.

Comment: silly me, thank you for pointing that out, I have managed to do it now. Thanks!